# Wordpress Page Template

Tags: wordpress

I'm going through some difficulty creating a wordpress page template which outputs a table containing the data I require.

I currently all the information correctly output but, the table and title reappears for every loop. Is it possible, and how, can I loop all the data into one table?

My page template is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: GamesDBTable
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
<?php 
$type = 'game';
$args=array(
 'post_type' => $type,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'paged' => $paged,
'orderby'=> 'title', 
'order' => 'ASC',
);
$temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use  
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
?>
<?php 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$game_identifier = get_game_identifier();
$developer = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'developer', '', ', ', '' ) );
$genre = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'genre', '', ', ', '' ) );
$payment = get_field('th_payment_model');
$arating = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, 'rating_average');
$rating = (($arating[0]) / 10);

;?>

<h4>Games Database</h2>
<table class="publisher">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Game Name <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                    <th>Genre <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                    <th>Payment Model <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th> 
                    <th>Developer <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                    <th>Rating <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>     
            <tr>
                <td><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'
rel='bookmark' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'>
<?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $genre; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $payment; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $developer; ?></td>
                <td><?php print_r($rating); ?>/10</td>

            </tr>
                        </tbody>
        </table>    


<?php
endwhile; endif; ?>

<!-- PAGINATION --><hr class="light"/><br style="clear:both;"/><div class="aligncenter"><?php echo vpt_pagination(); ?></div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #container -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the table header out of the loop and only include the table rows inside the loop;

```
    <table class="publisher">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Game Name <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                <th>Genre <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                <th>Payment Model <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th> 
                <th>Developer <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
                <th>Rating <a href="#" class="asc">a</a> <a href="#" class="desc">d</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

         <?php

         $game_identifier = get_game_identifier();
         $developer = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'developer', '', ', ', '' ) );
         $genre = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'genre', '', ', ', '' ) );
         $payment = get_field('th_payment_model');
         $arating = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, 'rating_average');
         $rating = (($arating[0]) / 10);

         ?>

            <tr>
                <td><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'rel='bookmark' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $genre; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $payment; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $developer; ?></td>
                <td><?php print_r($rating); ?>/10</td>

            </tr>


        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: That worked and everything is displayed in one table. However, now it seems that aside from the page title, nothing is getting the right data. Now Genre, Payment, Developer and Rating only takes the first post's data to be echoed. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Sorry man, that's me being sloppy and not copying across the section that assigns values to the variables.  Have updated it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much McNab!